# What does $m$ mean in $y = e^{-mx}$

Tags: calculus

What does $m$ mean in $y = e^{-mx}$

Should I treat this as a variable or a constant? Or is it something else?

Comment: Without context we can't tell you that, but it's most likely a constant.

Comment: All's it says is to 'find the derivative' the lists that equation

Comment: It's a variable constant.

Answer (score 2):

It is a variable that is constant and the derivative is:

$$y'(x) = -me^{-mx}$$

Comment: Ah makes sense. Thanks Zoti

Answer (score 0):

It is conventional to use the letters $p,q, m, n, i, j, k$ for Integer constants and $a,b,c,d$ for Real constants. $x,y,z$ and $w$ are usually used for Real variables (sometimes $z$ is reserved for as a Complex variable).